Is it possible to apply both Australia and New Zealand visas simultaenously for Indians
For Business visitor purpose, I'm planning to travel to both New Zealand and Australia.
Is it possible to apply both visa simulteanously and processed within 2 weeks for Indian citizen?

https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-processing-times/global-visa-processing-times tells us that for the Australian visa, currently 50% are processed in 6 days and 90% in 13 days (for business, it's much longer for tourist). But that's once you have assembled and provided all the documentation and so on. I don't think 2 weeks is realistic.

https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/visas/visa/business-visitors-visa tells us that for New Zealand, 80% are processed within 2 weeks.

New Zealand and Australia are different countries. While they may share visa application information, each country's application forms and processes to review, grant, or deny visas are independent. Because they are independent systems, you can (anyone can) apply for visas from both countries at the same time.
That said, your second question — can both applications be processed within two weeks — is unanswerable. We do not know the contents of your proposed applications...and even if we did, we'd be guessing about what either country's consular officers would decide based on that information. Even knowing a country's "usual processing time" doesn't guarantee a decision within the "usual" time. Guessing — or "opinion" — is off-topic here.

One issue is that many application processes require to show evidence that you can exit the country, and that may mean having the visa for the next country in the given itinerary. No idea if that applies to either.

@jcaron Quite true, may well apply to the OP's proposed itinerary...which we also don't know.

Another issue might be the need to submit a passport at some point. Getting two visas within two weeks seems unlikely to be achievable.
